# How to grep multiple lines?

Tags: grep, regular-expression, curl, text-formatting, json

Grep understands this :

```
curl https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ | grep "clipper-coin"
```

But not this :

```
curl https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ | grep "{*clipper-coin*}"
```

The output I expected was :

```
    {
        "id": "clipper-coin",
        "name": "Clipper Coin",
        "symbol": "CCCX",
        "rank": "100",
        "price_usd": "0.0159861038",
        "price_btc": "0.00000167",
        "24h_volume_usd": "28652.7472891",
        "market_cap_usd": "60356670.0",
        "available_supply": "3775570996.0",
        "total_supply": "5000000000.0",
        "max_supply": null,
        "percent_change_1h": "1.12",
        "percent_change_24h": "0.24",
        "percent_change_7d": "-6.9",
        "last_updated": "1564524066"
    }
```

What needs to be changed ?

Answer (score 4):

It understands it alright, but not as you would wish. The regular expression fragment `{*` matches zero or more `{` characters and `n*` matches zero or more `n` characters, so the full expression `{*clipper-coin*}` would match `{clipper-coin}`, `{{{clipper-coi}`, or `clipper-coinnnnnn}` etc.

Line-oriented text-processing utilities such as most of the utilities in the standard Unix text-processing toolbox are poor tools for parsing structured data such as JSON (even if extended with extra features for convenience by the GNU teams and others).  You very likely want to use a JSON parser instead.

To parse the returned JSON document for any `id` that is `bitcoin` (I see no `clipper-coin` in the output from that server), use a JSON parser, such as `jq`:

```
$ curl -s 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/' | jq '.[] | select(.id == "bitcoin")'
{
  "id": "bitcoin",
  "name": "Bitcoin",
  "symbol": "BTC",
  "rank": "1",
  "price_usd": "9626.82712316",
  "price_btc": "1.0",
  "24h_volume_usd": "13830555865.2",
  "market_cap_usd": "171817319309",
  "available_supply": "17847762.0",
  "total_supply": "17847762.0",
  "max_supply": "21000000.0",
  "percent_change_1h": "0.46",
  "percent_change_24h": "1.02",
  "percent_change_7d": "-3.11",
  "last_updated": "1564526372"
}
```

The `jq` expression `.[] | select(.id == "bitcoin")` would filter the returned JSON array for elements whose `id` key corresponds to the value `bitcoin`.

To pick out e.g. the `price_usd` value from this, use

```
$ curl -s 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/' | jq '.[] | select(.id == "bitcoin").price_usd'
"9630.84837853"
```

To get rid of the quotes, use `jq -r` in place of just `jq`.

See also the `jq` manual.

With `jq`, you could also easily make complicated queries, such as this one, which gets the symbol for the entry with the highest `percent_change_1h` value:

```
$ curl -s 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/' | jq 'max_by(.percent_change_1h | tonumber).symbol'
"WAX"
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks a little complicated, it feels like I am a little bit out of my depth, but I will read a bit more about that.

Comment: @pxoto It's far less complicated than trying to parse JSON with `grep`. It's also many times more robust and allows you to do additional types of querying against the dataset with the same syntax (rather than having to employ different tools to extract strings of text).